# copy from Second element of buffer to other buffer using memcpy

Tags: c

I want to copy the from Second element of one buffer to other buffer using memcpy instead of for loop.

```
for(i=1,j=0; i<12; i++,j++)
{
  buff[j] = buffer[i];
}
```

Can anybody suggest me

Comment: are you unable to read the documentation?

Comment: Please read here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html

Comment: I need to use memcpy(buff, buffer[1], 11), right??

Comment: Use `&buffer[1]`, instead of `buffer[1]` and it works if the data type is `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that they're both "true" arrays and thus not overlap:

```
memcpy(buff, buffer + 1, 11 * sizeof *buff);
```

This also assumes that they both have the same type, but uses `sizeof` to figure out what the item size is so it works regardless of the actual type of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
memcpy(buff, buffer + 1, 11 * sizeof (type) );
```

Where `type` is the type of `buff` and `buffer`.

[memcpy documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/memcpy.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

`dest` is `buff`
`src` is from second element in `buffer`
`n` is 11 (=12-1), so:

```
memcpy(buff, buffer+1, 11);
```

If `buff` and `buffer` are something larger  than `char` you need to adjust for size:

```
memcpy(buff, buffer+1, 11 * sizeof buffer[0]);
```

Comment: `n` is a size in bytes, not a number of elements.

Comment: Yeah, realised that the OP had failed to specify data type. I "autocorrected" to `char`, but that may of course be incorrect. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main ()
{
   char buffer[12] = "ABDCEFGHIJKL";
   char buff[12];
   memcpy(buff, buffer+1, strlen(buffer));
   return(0);
}
```

/*  Try this it may works....

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you.

memcpy ( &buffer,&buffer[1], sizeof(buffer)-1 );